# Why does setting a global root URL fail with PHP require_once?

Tags: php

I have created a file called init.php with the following code (which is included at the top of every page)

```
<?php
define('APP_ROOT', 'https://example.com/myapp');
?>
```

I can successfully echo APP_ROOT in a traditional link, even for sub-folders, as follows

```
<a href="<?php echo APP_ROOT ?>/subfolder/test.php">linktext</a>
```

What I cannot do is use the constant with PHP Require, for neither root files or files in sub-folders, as follows

```
<?php require_once(APP_ROOT . '/test.php') ?>
```

It returns the following error message:

> ```
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'https://example.com/myapp/test.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in...
> ```

Is it even possible to use a constant with require or include statements? If so, would appreciate any direction

Comment: The problem isn't the constant. The problem is that you can't use a URL with `require_once()`.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to do that, either. When you access a `.php` script on a webserver, it runs the script on the server. But `require` needs to read the source code of the script and run it locally.

Comment: You would include/require with a file path such as `myapp/` or `/var/www/myapp` not a URL.

Comment: requiring a URL path is not safe. Especially when parts of the path are obtained from a URL or in a way that the end user can manipulate one or more variables.

Comment: Originally, I tried to use dirname(__FILE__) as the value (versus) a URL, but it returns these crazy long (unfriendly) URLs, like this: https://example.com/home/setsmatt/public_html/example.com/myapp/subfolder/test.php

Comment: @Kodara You need to use two different constants.  One as your URL base, and one as your filepath base.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is running on multiple servers with different environments (locations from where your scripts run) the following idea may be useful to you:

- Do not give absolute path to include files on your server.
- Dynamically calculate the full path (absolute path)

**Hints**:
Use a combination of dirname(**FILE**) and subsequent calls to itself until you reach to the home of your '/index.php'. Then, attach this variable (that contains the path) to your included files.

One typical example is:

```
<?php 
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once(__ROOT__.'/config.php'); 
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php